# Creation tool for flutter?

Tags: flutter

does anyone know if there is a way to build a flutter UI just by dragging items onto the screen? Like I want a text layer, then I will just drag the text item on the screen and move it around? Like with swift?

Answer (score 3):

You can try https://flutterstudio.app/.

I am personally not a fan, but it may be useful for some tests.

Like all reverse engineering tools, be careful about the generated code.

Edit : I just see that it does not work well on Firefox.